# Merge multiple rows in table setting one column based on value in rows

Tags: mysql, snowflake

I have some data that looks something like this:

```
key B
1   true
1   false
2   false
2   false
```

And I want to roll it up so that if column `B` has two `false` values then the resulting value for `B` is `false`; otherwise, if there is a `true` and `false` value the value for `B` is `true`. Like this:

```
key B
1   true
2   false
```

Is there a way that this can be done with (Snowflake) SQL? I first thought of a pivot table but this doesn't quite seem to be what pivots do.

Comment: @McNets the Snowflake docs say: "Snowflake supports most of the commands and statements defined in SQL:1999." But I'm not sure how to tag that.

Comment: It doesn't matter,let it as [snowflake]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your text if any of them are true is must be true, otherwise is false:

```
select
    key,
    case 
      when sum(case when B is true then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then true
      else false
    end as result
from
   t
group by
    key;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c3611493aecd48c71932b1d2bb0b5e4f)*

Comment: this doesn't seem to do exactly what you intended, unless I'm mistaken. In the db<>fiddle you provided, the result column contains the sum value not true or false.

Comment: No, in fact it returns 1=true, 0=false, binary representation not the literals 'true' and 'false', but it is due to MySQL. Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228094/how-to-return-a-boolean-value-from-a-function-in-mysql